# type 'SliverAppBar' is not a subtype of type 'PreferredSizeWidget' FLUTTER issue

Tags: flutter, toolbar, floating, flutter-sliver

This issue *type 'SliverAppBar' is not a subtype of type 'PreferredSizeWidget' FLUTTER issue.* came while trying to create a **floating toolbar** using SilverAppBar in FLUTTER.

```
class AppTheme {
  setAppBar(context, String title) {
    return new AppBa(
      floating: true,
      pinned: true,
      title: Text(title,
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
          textDirection: TextDirection.ltr),
      flexibleSpace: Container(
        decoration: new BoxDecoration(
          gradient: new LinearGradient(
              colors: [
                hexToColor(themeColor1),
                hexToColor(themeColor2),
              ],
              begin: const FractionalOffset(0.0, 0.0),
              end: const FractionalOffset(1.0, 0.0),
              stops: [0.0, 1.0],
              tileMode: TileMode.clamp),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You need to wrap your slivers in `CustomScrollView`

Answer (score 1):

You should wrap your `SliverAppBar` with a `CustomScrollView`:

```
CustomScrollView(
   slivers: <Widget>[
      SliverAppBar(
        ...
      ),
      ...
   ]
);
```